# How to require one file, but load one or more with it

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-validation

I'm just getting started with Require.js.  I have the basics working.

Here's the issue I'm trying to solve: I'm using KnockoutJs and Knockout.validation.  I always use these files together.  So I'd like to do something where I only have to reference knockout and it will include knockout.validation.

This: (loading both knockout and knockout.validation)

```
define(["knockout"],
    function (ko) {     
        return {
            name: ko.observable();
        };
    }
);
```

Instead of this:

```
define(["knockout", "kovalidation"],
    function (ko) {     
        return {
            name: ko.observable();
        };
    }
);
```

I need the reference to ko, I just need the other(s) loaded.

Update:

based on the answer bellow I'm trying the bundle configuration option.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

My understanding is the config should look like:

```
<script>
    var require = {
        baseUrl: "/Scripts",
        bundles: {
            'knockout-3.0.0': ['knockout.validation']
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="views/home"></script>
```

Then in my home.js:

```
require(["knockout-3.0.0"], function (ko) {
   ...
});
```

Inside home.js, I would expect to see that knockout and knockout.validation are both loaded, but only knockout is loaded.

Update:

It seems like the bundle option in the configuration should do what I need, but at least at this point and with the information I have, it's not the right solution.  @daedalus28 gave some good information and a good example that helped me come up with a solution that is acceptable.  I have accepted that answer, if a better answer comes a long, please up vote it so we'll all know it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have a `LibraryPlugins` module which I load in my initial `require` call. In that module, I load up all of the plugins I want available everywhere - like knockout bindings, underscore mixins, jquery plugins, etc. Since it's one of my first require calls, I know the extensions it adds are generally available throughout my application

Sometimes I will take a more modular approach and have one extra module for each library which returns the library it's operating on (i.e. one for knockout with custom bindings that returns ko and one for underscore with custom mixins that returns a modified underscore). That approach ends up looking much like Louis's answer, but without the extra `map:*` config. Some modules expose themselves as a named module which makes it a bit more difficult to work with - that's when you'd use the map:* alias like in Louis's solution. For projects where I'm not using a ton of different libraries, I tend to just have one `LibraryPlugins` module as it is easier to manage when there's a small number of dependencies.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/yC2xk/) where I show both approaches.

For convenience I'll also paste the code in here:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout':'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min',
        'knockout.validation': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/1.0.2/knockout.validation.min',
        'underscore.core': 'http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min',
        'underscore.string': 'http://epeli.github.com/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore.core': {exports:'_'}
    }
});

// Approach 1: One module to load everything in advance
define('LibraryPlugins', ['knockout', 'knockout.validation'], function(ko){ });

// Approach 2: One module for each library
define('underscore', ['underscore.core', 'underscore.string'], function (_, _string) {
    _.mixin(_string.exports());
    return _;
});

require(['knockout', 'underscore', 'LibraryPlugins'], function(ko, _) {
    console.log(ko.validation);
    console.log(_.humanize);
});
```

Comment: is "_.mixin(_string.exports());" specific to underscore?  If it's a common function, will you give a brief explanation or provide a link that does?

Comment: `_.mixin(_string.exports())` is specific to the underscore.string library (https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string). It adds the library's string manipulation functions to the `_` object. The point was to demonstrate how to do arbitrary plugin/mixin stuff for any library, so I wanted an example besides knockout to demonstrate that the idea is useful as a pattern for requirejs apps in general. For a ko specific example, you could just as easily require knockout, add bindings to `ko.bindingHandlers`, and then return the `ko` object. The rest of your app wouldn't need to know the difference.

Comment: As a side note - for any library like ko.validation that modifies the core library object itself (ko in this case), you wouldn't need to do anything but require in knockout and ko.validation and then just return ko. If most of your plugins/mixins for a library follow that pattern and register themselves, you're probably better off with approach 1 as it's a bit simpler and there's less code involved.

Comment: I actually used approach 1 for one library and approach 2 for a different one.  Seems like this should be something built into the configuration of Require.  Until it is, this solution is working for me.

Comment: link I came across today that relates to this: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/259

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [bundle property of require.config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles)?

> Introduced in RequireJS 2.1.10: allows pointing multiple module IDs to
>   a module ID that contains a bundle of modules.

Comment: From the documentation, this seems like it is the correct way to do this, unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work.  I've updated the question with what I've tried.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the bundles config is used for script files that contain multiple named module declarations (such as the output of a previous build) so you can reference those modules directly in other places.

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is something like the shim:deps config but that works on modules that are AMD compliant - the docs (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) say to "Only use other 'shim' modules as dependencies for shimmed scripts, or AMD libraries that have no dependencies and call define() after they also create a global"

Comment: @max, this seems like what I want, but it's so new, I can't find any working examples.  If you have one, please share...

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the method used to load jQuery with `noConflict`. I'm adapting the following from the documentation on [that method](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap):

```
require.config({
    // Add this map config in addition to any baseUrl or
    // paths config you may already have in the project.
   map: {
      // '*' means all modules will get 'knockout-private'
      // for their 'knockout' dependency.
      '*': { 'knockout': 'knockout-private' },

      // 'knockout-private' wants the real knockout module
      // though. If this line was not here, there would
      // be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.
     'knockout-private': { 'knockout': 'knockout' }
   }
});
```

The `knockout-private` module would be something like this:

```
define(['knockout', 'kovalidation'], function (ko) {
    return ko;
});
```

You can add any number of other modules to `knockout-private`.